# How to generate a UTF-8 character with Ruby

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I am using Ruby, and I need to generate one UTF-8 character by an integer.

eg: if `id = 65(10)`, I need to get the UTF-8 char which is encoded 00a1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
65.pack('U')
```